# Save file which is fetched from email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments

I want to save the attachment files which I have fetched from the email. Is there any way to achieve it?

File.Create(path of file) only creates a blank file with that name. It doesn't have the actual contents of the file.

Comment: Usually the modules that read attachments have a save to disk function, or else you need to place here your code to see how you keep your data for show how to save them. How ever if you search on google you can find how to save to file - is very simple and basic stuff.

Comment: Well, the context of your question is quite inclear : How do you fetch mail? using pop3? in outlook client?

Comment: @Kek I have used a dll to fetch the email. through pop3 method

Comment: Then, again, it depends on the dll... The harder part is to get the data of the attachment as a byte[], then you can call File.WriteAllBytes... For the former part, we can do nothing here as long as we don't know this dll you ar using

Comment: @Kek The code of the dll is too long and it can't be posted here. I got the classes from Internet and combined them. But, I was not getting the right way. Let me find the method of getting byte[] in the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET
It seems everything is already done for you...

Comment: does it provide the facility of saving the emails also?